# How to edit web.config file WordPress IIS

Tags: wordpress, iis, web-config, url-rewriting, permalinks

I've installed WordPress on Windows Server 2008 running IIS 7.5.

I'm trying to edit the web.config file in %SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot\wordpress\ to add rewrite rule as documented at http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/enabling-pretty-permalinks-in-wordpress but I keep getting the error "Please check if this file is opened in another program." (editing in Notepad++)

I've stopped the wordpress application pool in IIS Manager, then tried again, but still getting same error. Not sure what program is using this file, no one is viewing the wordpress site and no one is logged into the server besides me.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the notepad editor as an administrator (i.e right click notepad++ and click on run as administrator). While it is opened, open your the file you want to edit with notepad. Edit your file and save, you should be good.
Regards